# Nginx and Wordpress permalink with .php extension

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

My client's website use Wordpress. The permalink is set to `/%postname%.php`. See there is `.php`. So an URL would be look like `http://www.example.com/article-url.php`.
I am using Nginx and PHP-FPM. That permalink setting did not work as I got `File not found` error.

Here is my Nginx server block

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/example.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Here is the error log says `FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading re    sponse header from upstream ...`

How to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190757/nginx-permalinks-with-php-in-url-not-working).. So what I need to do is to add `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` under php location

My server block now:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/example.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                    deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, really helpful!! :)